# Great Book on Probability and Statistics (for Computer Scientists)

Tags: probability, reference-request, statistics, computer-science

I'm a Computer Science sophomore and we're studying Probability and Statistics (fundamentals and all). The teacher recommends a book which I don't like since it does not even try and explain everything.

So, can you recommend me a few great books on Probability and Statistics and if such exists, with an accent on Computer Science?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks has some free books listed there

Answer (score 6):

Some references you can use:

1. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/lecture-notes/
2. My favorite: http://www.rle.mit.edu/rgallager/notes.htm
3. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2005/lecture-notes/
4. http://books.google.com/books/about/Probability_and_Random_Processes_With_Ap.html?id=8C-VQgAACAAJ
5. Gentle introduction for CS folks - http://people.ee.duke.edu/~kst/

Answer (score 3):

The book [Introduction to Probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/188652940X) by Bertsekas seems good.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice compiled list [here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-best-books-to-learn-probability.html). The WEKA book is also a great resource to own.

Answer (score 1):

Use this book :
Probability Theory: The Logic of Science

This is one of the best, enjoyable and engaging books on probability.

While reading it, you may feel that the writer is talking to you in person.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Introduction to Probability, Statistics, and Random Processes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0990637204) . Chapter 1 to 9 are dedicated for probability and statistics. This book is really easy and simple. The good part is that you can read this book [online](http://www.probabilitycourse.com/) for free!

For more depth reading without involving too much mathematics I would recommend [Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/188652923X). You can download the complete solution of the book from [here](http://athenasc.com/probbook.html).
[Probability and Random Variables A Beginner's Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521644453) is also a worth of reading and it can be used as complementary .

Answer (score 1):

Bertsekas wrote a pretty decent book. Other than that Probability and Random Processes for Electrical and Computer Engineers by Gubner is worth a try if you need a book that is easy to follow and fits into a standard college level course.